# Row-wise calculations in data.table long data format

Tags: r, data.table

Hi Stackover flow community

I am new with learning R so will appreciate your patience. I am learning **data.table** and want to do row-wise computations using data.table computations. See the image attached with 6 columns (the image only shows a small subset of data): [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bt8CS.png)

I want to calculate unemployment rate which is 'Unemployed total/Labour force total'. Because the data is in long format both Unemployed total and Labour force total are within the column 'variable'. I want unemployment rate calculated by 'sex', 'region' and by 'data_type'.

My question is: How to do such a calculation (using data.table not dplyr) for unemployment rate as I ideally want the results for unemployment rate in rows.

e.g.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mvHb.png)

Thanks, and I have also attached the code which can help you with producing the raw dataset.

```
rm(list=ls())

#Bring in all installed packages
library(readabs)

library(tidyverse)

library(dplyr)

library(stringr)

library(lubridate)

library(data.table)

library(tidyr)

library(fy)

library(psych)

library(plyr)

#**************************************************************************************************************

#Labour force indicators

abs_labour_force_base <- read_abs(cat_no = '6202.0', 
                                  tables = 12,
                                  series_id = NULL,
                                  metadata = TRUE,
                                  show_progress_bars = FALSE,
                                  retain_files = FALSE,
                                  check_local = FALSE
)

#split out series column

abs_labour_force_base <- separate_series(abs_labour_force_base)

setDT(abs_labour_force_base)

# create raw data set

d <- 
  lf_monthly_qld  <- abs_labour_force_base[
      series_1 %in% c("Unemployed total","Labour force total") & 
      series_2 %in% c("Males","Female") &
      series_3 %in% c("Australia","Victoria") &
      series_type %in% c("Seasonally Adjusted", "Trend") &
      date > as_date("2023-01-08"),]


keep_cols = c("date", "series_1", "series_2","series_3","value","series_type")

d <- d[, ..keep_cols]


colnames(d)<-c("date","variable","sex","region","value","data_type")
```

I haven't tried much because I wasn't sure if the best way to do this manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dcast`:

```r
d <- 
  abs_labour_force_base[
    series_1 %in% c("Unemployed total","Labour force total") & 
      series_2 %in% c("Males","Females") &
      series_3 %in% c("Australia","Victoria") &
      series_type %in% c("Seasonally Adjusted", "Trend") &
      date > "2023-01-08"]

Ans <- dcast(d, date + series_type + series_2 + series_3 ~ series_1, value.var = "value")
Ans[, "UnemploymentRate" := `Unemployed total` / `Labour force total`]
```

Note the small error in your original question `series_2 %in% c("Males", "Females")` (it was `"Female"`). You can use package hutils and `%ein%` to avoid these sort of errors.

```r
library(hutils)
abs_labour_force_base[series_2 %ein% c("Males", "Female")]
#> Error: `rhs` contained Female, but this value was not found in `lhs = series_2`. All values of `rhs` must be in `lhs`. Ensure you have specified `rhs` correctly.
```

Comment: Thanks, you that's very kind of you for your prompt reply.